# How to achieve DB migration in Falcon framework

Tags: migration, falconframework

Just like Flask have `Flask-Migrate` to achieve migration. Does Falcon have anything like Flask?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQLAlchemy as an ORM with Falcon, you can try [Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) for database migrations (which is what `Flask-Migrate` uses under the hood for managing migrations within Flask applications).